# Copy pipe output and execute a command on it and save in a file, all without stopping the pipe cycle

Tags: c, multiprocessing, pipe, exec, parent-child

I'd like to launch the command `wc -c` on every argument. I used pipes to communicate between the processors.

Example: `./test cat data.txt : grep left : grep And`.

this should be launched on the terminal and execute `wc -c` on every command and save it in a file, and the child continue its thread.

this is my where I'm stuck: (without error handling for simpler code)

```
int out = open("counter.txt", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0777);
for (int j = 0; j < numPipes + 1; j++){
        pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0) { // child
            //if not first command
            if(j != 0)
                dup2(pipes[(j-1) * 2], 0);
            //if not last command
            
            if(j != numPipes)
                dup2(pipes[j*2 + 1], 1);

            
            //int out = open("count.txt", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0777);
            //dup2(1, out);

            for(int i = 0; i < 2*numPipes; i++){
                close(pipes[i]);
            }
            
            if( execvp(argv[indice_debut[j]], argv + indice_debut[j]) < 0 ){
                perror(argv[indice_debut[j]]);
                return 1;
            }
            
        } else if(pid < 0){
            perror("error");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    //parent

    //!!! is this part supposed to be in parent or child ?
    //char* args[] = {"wc",argv[indice_debut[numPipes+1]],NULL};
    //execvp("wc","-c",args);
    //dup2(out, pipes[3]);
...
```

What can i do so far ? I'm stuck

Comment: I don't think you can do that. If the output is piped to `wc -l`, it can't also be piped to `grep`.

Comment: @Barmar what do you think the solution would be ? just the idea, i thought about creating an extra fork but i won't be able to launch 2 exec in one child

Comment: You need something like the `tee` command, which copies its standard input to multiple outputs.